# Is it possible to open an excel file in its current location not download it

Tags: html, intranet

I am writing a small web site for a company Intranet and have the following question that may be simple. Is it possible to open an Excel file from it's current location on the network instead of downloading it. So that any changes made are made to the actual file and not a downloaded version of it?

Thanks

Matt

Comment: Most browsers block this for security reasons, but I think you can make IE follow `\\SERVERNAME\SHARE\FILE` style links by putting the site into a trusted/local intranet context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, but then you would have to specify the address of the file in the local network, not as an HTTP address on the web server.

The user would naturally need to have access to the file on the network share, with write permission.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, this one works as do a couple of others. They work in IE but not Google Chrome, but we use IE at work so hay ho.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use Edge with IE mode to open intranet files. Edge and Chrome usually sees them as local files and automatically downloads them. Even if you select the option "Open certain file types automatically after downloading" in Chrome.

Try and use Edge with IE mode. This gives you the advantage of using a modern browser and still access ancient websites like intranet pages.

1. Open Edge
2. Type this in your address bar: 'edge://settings/defaultbrowser'
3. Slide the Allow sites to be reloaded in Internet Explorer toggle to ON.
4. Restart Microsoft Edge.

Edge with IE is now enabled

1. Open a new tab
2. Type in your intranet link
3. Right click on your current tab
4. Click "Reload tab in Internet Explorer mode"

Your intranet page is accessible

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/internet-explorer-mode-in-microsoft-edge-6604162f-e38a-48b2-acd2-682dbac6f0de

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible to open a remote excel file across HTTP and write changes back to it.

Let's consider some other things you might be trying to do.

If you are running excel, all you can open are files visible to the file system APIs. That means files on your local disk and network file systems accessible via CIFS. Mapped drive letters, `\\` pathnames, that sort of thing.

If you set up an Excel file for download from a web server, it will always be downloaded. Excel won't open it 'in place'.

The Microsoft technology solution that addresses what you seem to be asking for is Sharepoint.

Comment: This is not *exactly* what he's asking (I thought the same thing at first). He's asking about a local network resource

Comment: @Pek I thought upwards, downwards, and sideways. I'll try some more. It's really off-topic in any case but I'm out of close votes.

Comment: if I understand the question correctly, he's asking about how to link to an Excel file in the LAN. If it's available through a share, it's possible in IE, but otherwise you're right. And that's a shame really - it's 2011, and people still have to download, open, save, and upload things to alter a remote file.

Answer (score 0):

Anything you open from a HTTP connection I believe is "downloaded" to the client. Its more how you "uploade" the changes.

But if thats what the customer wants I have some alternatives:

1) Use Dropbox or similar filesharing utils. Once someone saves a document in Dropbox, its automatically uploaded to the Dropbox account. The free version allows up to 2 GB of data. Thats quite a few Excel files.

2) Use Gmail/Google Apps. If you do you get 1 GB space for online documents. You can upload Office files suchs as Excel and they will be converted an online editable from within the Google Docs. You can share the files within the domain or even externally if you make that setting the admin part. Afterwards you can also download/export the Spreadsheet as Excel format. I havent tested how much of the standards you loose but ofcause its not a full Excel.

3) wait for Microsoft to finish their Office online. I bet that Excel version will do exactly what you are currently asking for by using some special plugin or MSIE9 technics. But I dont really know yet.

Hope some of this gave you some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in a network share on the same domain (or reachable from the domain your app is running from), it is possible, provided that

1. The share is readable and writeable by the domain\user the app runs under (via ownership or  assigned role.)
2. The file is shareable (IIRC). This is important if multiple users (or apps) need to access it.

Other than that, a \domain\location path should be treatable just like a local (or disk mounted) path.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML document, create/place a link:

```
<a href='file:///H:/docs/foo/bar.xls'>Your Excel File</a>
```

Substitite your network UNC path for `H:/docs/foo/bar.xls`. Note the slashes instead of the regular UNC backslashes.

Comment: This will not work in any modern browser, except as said, maybe IE if you add the site to the correct zone.