# how to run excel application on html button through browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to make a button in html page so that when a user click it an excel application get starts.

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" href="to popup excel sheet">click</button>
```

Comment: You mean windows excel application?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is a stateless protocol. What that means for you is that when your users download a file from the intranet via http, they are downloading a copy, rather than the original. Any changes they make will only appear in their copy, and then you end up with loads of copies of the same workbook with different, possibly overlapping changes. You don't want that!

And also ... how are your users even going to upload their changes?

You need to create a shared folder on your network and put the workbook there. You can then use the `file:///SERVER/PATH/FILE.xls` format in your `<a />` links on your intranet to direct your user to the actual file on the server.

---

I would recommend you start by creating a simple html doc on your desktop to get familiar with the `file:///` path format.
Eg

```
<html>
    <head />
    <body>
        <a href="file:///SERVER/PATH/FILE.xls">Click</a>
    <body>
 <html>
```

save that in notepad and rename the extension from `.txt` to `.html`.

You can also type `file:///` paths straight into windows explorer's address bar which allow for testing paths without resorting to the html document mentioned above.

**UNFORTUNATELY**! It seems that the browsers default behavior is to always download a link rather than open it (even if it is a local resource), so if you actually want to open it then you must resort to changing your browser intranet permissions to allow JS to access local resources, which then allows you to use the technique below.

---

This article (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113678/How-to-execute-a-Local-File-using-HTML-Application) uses

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function RunFile() {
    WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    WshShell.Run("c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe", 1, false);
    }
</script>
```

to open notepad. You can use command line arguments with Excel.exe (https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Command-line-switches-for-Excel-321cf55a-ace4-40b3-9082-53bd4bc10725) to tell it what the file path is...

```
Excel.exe "C:\PATH\Excel.xls"
```

Refer link: [Open excel file through normal html link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472397/open-excel-file-through-normal-html-link?answertab=active#tab-top)