# VBA-Excel in Laravel

Tags: laravel, excel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, vba

I have a question if it can happen. I have an excel file that has macro enabled VBA. It has a button that will trigger the VBA for my excel. I was just wondering if it is available to trigger a VBA in Laravel app. I have like an upload button in laravel but when i click it, it will first trigger the button in excel that triggers the VBA then it will read the upload excel function. Do you think it is possible? And how?

Comment: Seems like a wrong way to go about it... just launch the vba macro directly from the commandline using php shell_exec($command) ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you asked the same question 3 hours ago here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684820/trigger-vba-macros-application-in-laravel/49686864#49686864`

Comment: @AlekseiMaide Well, I'd like to see how you launch a macro at the local side with PHP running on the server? Or I'd like to see the server that has Excel installed to run macros (from uploaded files!!). "*Seems like a wrong way to go about it*"

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Obviously your PHP server is LOCAL to something !!! (!!! 's because why not.)

Comment: @AlekseiMaide And yes, PHP is then running on a server so: I'd like to see the server that has Excel installed to run macros (from uploaded files!!) • Why not? Because that would be the biggest security hole on a server I had ever seen.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ but does anything stop you from doing exactly that? Whether it is a good decision is a totally different question :) It might just be that he will be the only one uploading the files and there won't be any side effects if some "bad" file were uploaded, so it might actually be a valid solution to a business problem.

Comment: @AlekseiMaide Yes, sanity should stop you from doing this. Or are you going to drive with 100 km/h against a wall just because you can? Always a  good idea to point out that you actually can drive with 100 km/h against walls isn't it? • And I would fire that admin who installs Excel on a sever to run macros.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ we don't know the actual business problem. Driving 100km/h against the wall might be a better alternative than crashing at 200km/h ? :D There are always tradeoffs