# Is there a way to import/utilize macro worksheets (VBA in Excel) in modern browsers such as Google Chrome

Tags: excel, vba, laravel

I was browsing the internet looking for possible solutions to my problem. For a job I have to extract data from an Excel worksheet in order to turn that data into something like a scheduling module. It's meant to give the customer insight into the progress his employees are making (most prominent).

Now since I couldn't find a specific answer and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684820/trigger-vba-macros-application-in-laravel) suggesting the only real way was using internet explorer, I was wondering if there are better and more modern ways to do this.

My framework of choice would be Laravel. I thought I'd mention it in case it matters for the possible solution or not. I am really scratching my head here because I cannot imagine that with today's technology we would still have to rely on Internet Explorer.

If anyone has tips, suggestions, anything that helps me: I would really appreciate it.

Comment: We must understand that VBA was created by Microsoft and they developed their way of Internet Explorer pages manipulations. Then, a third party (Selenium) gave acces to such manipulations in Chrome. Besides this two options, VBA offers access to the page without using a browser. It depends on what you need. You can download files using only API calls and you can also pages manipulate using a reference to `Microsoft HTML Object Library` and `Microsoft Internet Controls`...

Comment: You should look up automating RESTful calls (GET, POST etc.) using `MSXML2.ServerHTTP60` - you don't need to use Internet Explorer, you just use background calls in Excel. E.g. answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38246789/how-do-we-use-restful-apis-from-excel-macros-vba

Comment: I thought I'd add my specific idea: The customer currently uses Excel sheets with macro's to fulfill the goal of keeping track of progress. He requested that a site be built to take over this task. I want to get macro data from the worksheet (e.g. whether a certain button is red (unfinished) or green (finished) and display that on the webpage).